# Await Message Components for specific user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to use createMessageComponentCollector(MessageButton), but I don't know what code would allow the opponent to be able to press it alone.

If someone knows, please help me!

Here my code:

```js
        const filter = m => m.customId === 'accept' || 'decline' && m.author.id === member.id
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter, max: 1, time: 30000 });

        collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
            if (m.customId === 'accept') {
                await m.deferUpdate();
                return await m.editReply({ content: `ACCEPT!`, embeds: [], components: [] });
            } else if (m.customId === 'decline') {
                await m.deferUpdate();
                return await m.editReply({ content: `DECLINE!`, embeds: [], components: [] });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with all the new Discord lingo or the intricacies of DiscordJS 13, but I do believe your filter is incorrect. If your intent is to check if customId is 'accept' or 'decline', you need to spell it out: `m.customId === 'accept' || m.customId === 'decline'`;

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, thanks for telling me a lot, brother. :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the code

- CODE HERE:

```js
        const filter = m => m.customId === 'accept' || 'decline' && m.member.id === member.id
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter, max: 1, time: 30000 });

        collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
            if (m.customId === 'accept') {
                await m.deferUpdate();
                return await m.editReply({ content: `ACCEPT!`, embeds: [], components: [] });
            } else if (m.customId === 'decline') {
                await m.deferUpdate();
                return await m.editReply({ content: `DECLINE!`, embeds: [], components: [] });
            }
        });
```

```js
const filter = m => m.customId === 'accept' || 'decline' && m.author.id === member.id
```

`m.author.id` use for djs@v12,
but for djs@v13 use `m.member.id`